# jQuery global custom events and live() doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to get to grips with jQuery live() when combined with global custom events.

I've jsfiddled (and simplified) an example from jQuery docs itself.

Using `bind()` works:
http://jsfiddle.net/joshcomley/zShnd/

Using `live()` doesn't:
http://jsfiddle.net/joshcomley/QJDdH/

I understand there are differences in how `live()` and `bind()` work, and that with `live()` events can be cancelled if another event in the tree returned false etc.

I've read as many blog posts as I can get my hands on, but nothing out there seems to explain a *combination* of `live()` and *global* custom events.

I just cannot figure out why `live()` won't work in this example!

Can anyone help explain this to me?

Comment: +1, [jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) only gives an example of triggering the `p` element, but not by global events.

Comment: I would suggest that you [create an issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket?redirectedfrom=) at the jQuery website. If they think it is overhead, they will close your issue and give good comments on their reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to target the elements you want when you trigger the event.

so use

```
$('p').trigger('myCustomEvent');
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/QJDdH/2/

---

**Update**

This seems to be a decision from the jQuery team..

quote from the [source code of the trigger method <sup>github source</sup>](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L300-303)

```
 // Handle a global trigger   
 if (!elem ) {   
 // Don't bubble custom events when global (to avoid too much overhead)   
 event.stopPropagation();
```

The only alternative i can think of (*besides tinkering with the jQuery source*) would be to do a

```
$('*').trigger('myCustomEvent');
```

but it seems like it could be expensive.. (*again not global in the sense that non DOM bound events will not get triggered*)..

Comment: Yes, but this isn't a global event then is it? Or am I confusing terminology?

Comment: @joshcomley, yes it is not... Looks like it is a distinct choice made by jQuery team. Have a look at the update in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the following which is registring the live click event with the name myCustomEvent.

```
$("button").bind("click.myCustomEvent", function(e, myName, myValue) {
    $(this).siblings("p").text("I've changed!");
});
```